# Dynamic date select list creation

Tags: apex, date, selectlist

I need to create a drop down with date values Like

```
March 28-April 27
February 28-March 27
January 28-February 27
December 28-January 27
November 28-December 27
October 28-November 27
September 28-October 27
```

any ideas to achieve this ,

> This is the code that I have.  This code works, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to accomplish this

```
for (Integer i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            optValue = String.valueOf(startdate)+'_'+String.valueOf(enddate);
            optText = startMonth+' '+String.valueOf(startdate.day())+'-'+endMonth+' '+String.valueOf(enddate.day());
            options.add(new selectOption(optValue,optText));
        }
        else
        {
            endDateTime = startDateTime.addDays(-1); // getting the end date from past start date by subtracting 1 day
            enddate = startdate.addDays(-1);
            endMonth = endDateTime.format('MMMMM');

            if(dateValue == 29 && startDateTime.format('MMMMM').equals('February') && !startMonthName.equals('February'))
            {
                if(!date.isLeapYear(startDateTime.year()))  // if it is a leap year february month will have 29 days so we are not adding 1 day to it   
                {
                    startdate = startdate.addMonths(-1).addDays(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    startdate = startdate.addMonths(-1);
                }
            }
            else if(dateValue == 30 && startDateTime.format('MMMMM').equals('February') && !startMonthName.equals('February'))
            {
                if(!date.isLeapYear(startDateTime.year()))  // if it is a leap year february month will have 29 days so we are not adding 2 days to it   
                {
                    startdate = startdate.addMonths(-1).addDays(2);
                }
                else
                {
                    startdate = startdate.addMonths(-1).addDays(1);
                }
            }
            else if(dateValue == 31 && startDateTime.format('MMMMM').equals('February') && !startMonthName.equals('February'))
            {
                if(!date.isLeapYear(startDateTime.year()))  // if it is a leap year february month will have 29 days so we are not adding 3 days to it   
                {
                    startdate = startdate.addMonths(-1).addDays(3);
                }
                else
                {
                    startdate = startdate.addMonths(-1).addDays(2);
                }
            }
            else if(dateValue == 31 && startMonthDays == 31)   //suppose the number of days in the user entered month and datevalue = 31 we check every month and enter the end date of that month
            {
                startdate = startdate.addMonths(-1);
                Integer numberOfDays = date.daysInMonth(startdate.year(),startdate.month());
                startdate = date.newInstance(startdate.year(),startdate.month(),numberOfDays);
            }
            else //this comes under normal condition
            {
                startdate = startdate.addMonths(-1); // getting the start date from past start date by subtracting 1 month
            }
            startDateTime = datetime.newInstance(startdate.year(), startdate.month(), startdate.day());
            startMonth = startDateTime.format('MMMMM');

            optValue = String.valueOf(startdate)+'_'+String.valueOf(enddate); // adding the values to a list
            optText = startMonth+' '+String.valueOf(startdate.day())+'-'+endMonth+' '+String.valueOf(enddate.day());
            options.add(new selectOption(optValue,optText));
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried to create them so far? Have you familiarised yourself with the Date manipulation methods?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'the code seems too big'.  Did this code fail? Was there an error message?

Comment: the code didn't failed me, but few advised me to reduce the line of codes . So i thought there might be some other way

Comment: So this code does work?  You're just asking if there is a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: absolutely . !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well how about this?

```
List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>(); 
datetime d = datetime.newinstanceGMT(2013,3,28);   //Start date for the first period
for (integer x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
    String formattedStart = d.addMonths(-x).formatGMT('MMMMM dd');
    String formattedEnd = d.addMonths(-x+1).addDays(-1).formatGMT('MMMMM dd');
    String fullOption = formattedStart + '-' + formattedEnd;
    System.debug(fullOption);
    options.add(new selectOption(fullOption,fullOption));
}
```

It produces the same output

```
DEBUG|March 28-April 27
DEBUG|February 28-March 27
DEBUG|January 28-February 27
DEBUG|December 28-January 27
DEBUG|November 28-December 27
DEBUG|October 28-November 27
DEBUG|September 28-October 27
DEBUG|August 28-September 27
DEBUG|July 28-August 27
```

The datetime methods are pretty good at coping with month ends. So for example if you start off with 31st October, addMonths(-1) will give you 30th September, addMonths(-2) will give you 31st August. So you don't need to do so much coding yourself unless you have unusual requirements for how you want the date periods calculated.

Comment: This is awesome .

Comment: sorry to bother you again , while using the date 07/30/2013 after february the date values in the select list gets changed, can u fix this

Comment: Sure, I've amended the code now.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to somehow build these date ranges dynamically, but you can just use Vf and use a list of SelectOption

**In VF**

```
<apex: selectList size="1" value="{!myDateRange}">
     <apex:selectOptions value="{!DateRangeOptions}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

**Controller**

```
public List<SelectOption> getDateRangeOptions() {

        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>(); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('March 28-April 27','March 28-April 27')); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('February 28-March 27','February 28-March 27')); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('January 28-February 27','January 28-February 27')); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('December 28-January 27','December 28-January 27'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('November 28-December 27','November 28-December 27')); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('October 28-November 27','October 28-November 27')); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('September 28-October 27','September 28-October 27'));          
        return options;     
}
```

Comment: sorry i missed to mention that , i will get the date value from the user , and then i have to calculate the date